# Remove multiple CIFS shares using for loop in AIX

Tags: aix, cifs

I want to unmount multiple CIFS shares on my AIX LPAR using for loop. I created a file named cifs.txt containing all CIFS shares. Will my command work?

```
for i in $(cat cifs.txt); do rmcifsmnt -f $i; done
```

Comment: You're calling rmcifsmnt which "Removes a CIFS mount from the /etc/filesystems file and unmounts the entry if it is mounted" but only "want to unmount". Which do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Your existing loop runs the risk of expanding any wildcards in the filenames *and* removes the corresponding mount(s) from /etc/filesystems. If the mounts are given, one per line, in cifs.txt, then to unmount them:

```
< cifs.txt xargs -n 1 umount
```

or

```
< cifs.txt xargs -n 1 rmcifsmnt -N -f
```

Correspondingly, if you want to unmount them *and* remove them from /etc/filesystems:

```
< cifs.txt xargs -n 1 rmcifsmnt -f
```

`xargs` will do the work of parsing cifs.txt line-by-line and passing each line as an argument to the `umount` or `rmcifsmnt` commands (at the end).